# Visio 2013 - Flowchart Legend

Tags: charts, microsoft-visio-2013, flowchart

I get the following error when I try to insert a legend into my visio diagram (flowchart):

> There are no suitable data graphics on this page.  If you apply a
>   data graphic, you can usa a legend to clarify the meaning of a data
>   bar, icon set, or color by value item.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because you don't know how to use the Data Graphics and Legend features of Visio 2013.
So here are some Websites explaining how to use this feature:

- [Enhance your data with data graphics](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/visio-help/enhance-your-data-with-data-graphics-HA102749262.aspx)
- [Data-linked diagrams: Building data graphics](http://blogs.office.com/2013/05/20/data-linked-diagrams-building-data-graphics/)
- [Data-linked diagrams: Creating a diagram](http://blogs.office.com/2013/04/18/data-linked-diagrams-creating-a-diagram/)
- [VIDEO: Custom Shapes and Data Graphics in Visio 2013](http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/custom-shapes-and-data-graphics-in-visio-2013/10thq1u8m?cpkey=e803f0fe-b7c1-4ec1-a984-fb00496e88fc%257c%257c%257c%257c)
- [VIDEO: Advanced Data Linking in Visio 2013](http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/advanced-data-linking-in-visio-2013/10tvxbp3k?cpkey=e803f0fe-b7c1-4ec1-a984-fb00496e88fc%257c%257c%257c%257c)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a web based [flowchart maker](https://creately.com/diagram-type/flowchart) to create flowcharts.
     You can export them as images /svg or even embed them as live diagrams on blogs/websites.
 There are 100s of templates and examples of flowchart to be used free.